# How to split and concatenate a string in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a NameString which is a combination of first name and last name and I want to create a new string from `NameString` to swap the first and last names to create ReverseNameString. For example,

```
First Name   Last Name    NameString          ReverseNameString
John         Kennedy      John Kennedy        Kennedy John
Mary B H     Kennedy      Mary B H Kennedy    Kennedy Mary B H
```

How can I do this using scala? Note there can be multiple words in first name but not in last name.

I have used `NameString.split(" ").last` to get last name but I am not sure how to get rest of the first name to concatenate these both. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `last` gives you the last element in a collection, `init` gives you all but the last element in a collection.

Comment: _"...can be multiple words in first name but not in last name."_ Not applicable in the real world, e.g. Eddie Van Halen

Answer (score 1):

Extracting smaller strings out of a bigger one can be done with either `str.split(separator)` or `str.substring(start, end)`. Concatenation is just `str1 + str2`.

Using spaces as separator is super unreliable here. I could e.g. decide to split after 5th char based on thefirst line, so 2nd column would be `Name`, empty string, `B H` instead of `Last Name`, `Kennedy`, `Kennedy`.

Either you have a fixed length of each column predefined and then you can use `substring` or you have to design some algorithm which finds all new columns candidates by canning the whole input once, and then split lines into columns based on that, which still doesn't guarantee good result. You can also have a hardcoded list of possible column names, use a regexp to detect where each of them begins, and use that to break the following strings.

I don't want to write a whole algorithm here because I saw this as a recruitment assignment before, so I am afraid that having this answer here would encourage cheating.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. One example is:

```
def reverseName(name: String): String = {
  val names = name.split(' ')
  (names.last +: names.dropRight(1)).mkString(" ")
}
```

Then calling:

```
val names = Seq("John Kennedy", "Mary B H Kennedy")
println(names.map(reverseName))
```

will output:

```
List(Kennedy John, Kennedy Mary B H)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/NtbMKeTHR8abjXPAjVW8hQ).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways. I am using `yield` to concatenate all the firsts names. This answer is just another option to you.

```
object BasicString {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val nameStringList = List("John Kennedy", "Mary B H Kennedy")
    nameStringList.foreach(s => println(s"original: $s"))

    val result = reverseNames(nameStringList)

    result.foreach(s => println(s"result: $s"))
  }

  def reverseNames(nameStringList: List[String]): List[String] = {
    nameStringList.map { name =>
      val nameArray = name.split(" ")
      val firstsName = for {i <- 0 until nameArray.length - 1} yield (nameArray(i) + " ")
      (nameArray(nameArray.length - 1) + " " + firstsName.mkString)
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```
original: John Kennedy
original: Mary B H Kennedy
result: Kennedy John 
result: Kennedy Mary B H
```